# Replace numbers that start with a "-" (hyphen) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

So I exported a mySQL database, so far everything has been easy to edit in Notepad++.
However, every new line starts with a `-123456` random number string.

Is there a way to remove all string that start with `-`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is. It's finding and replacing a line through **regular expressions**:

```
-[0-9]+ *(.*)
```

Edit: shorter form: `-\d+ *(.*)`

Then all you have to do is replace the whole line with the first group, which is `.*`. This will remove the number there.

[image]

If you want to delete the whole line, then you don't need groups. But you need the end of line character to be removed.
So:

1. Remove the matched **regexp** line string. If you don't want to delete empty lines you already have than I suggest replacing your string with something unique like `RRRRRRRRRRR`.
   [image]
2. Then, you need to use **extended  mode**, not regular expressions, to remove `RRRRRRRRRRR` plus the new line character (depending on the file format, the new line might represent two bytes or one byte, but on Windows files is CR+LF which in Notepad++ represents `\r\n`), by replacing them with nothing.
   [image]

Comment: That was just awesome! I used (-[0-9]+) and it removed just what I wanted, thank you so very much!

Comment: I think you want to remove white spaces as well, that's the " *". I guess I complicated things a bit. I guess (-[0-9]+ *) works just fine for you. There's actually a shorter form... (-\d+ *)